# How to query for time delta in minutes?

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to get the time delta in minutes between two times. The query returned incorrect time deltas:

[image]

`time_delta` should be 133 and 90 respectively.

```
SELECT arrival_time, discharge_time
    ,STRFTIME("%H%M", discharge_time)-STRFTIME("%H%M", arrival_time) AS time_delta
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not work because it converts the dates to *string* representations (in format `%H%M`), then it tries to substract the two strings - which does not do what you expect.

You can, instead, convert the dates to unix epochs, so you get a time difference in seconds :

```
select arrival_time, discharge_time,
    unixepoch(discharge_time) - unixepoch(arrival_time) as time_delta_in_seconds
from mytable;
```

`unixepoch()` is a syntax shortcut for `strftime('%s', ...)`, as explained in [the SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).